# How to specify the equivalent of ppn (on PBS) in SGE queuing system?

Tags: queue, gridengine

Is there a way to specify the `ppn` ( or equivalent ) in `SGE` ? i don't want to use all cpus in one node so i will be able to have more memory per core. ( In PBS you would do `-l nodes=16:ppn=2` for exemple)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a parallel environment in order for a job to run in parallel on multiple nodes. Read `man sge_pe` for details. When running in a parallel environment, the memory request is interpreted as being per-slot.